# Result of function in function JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function

I'm beginner and I think the answer is easy, but after searching I'm not able find the answer.

I try to log "tab" but it seem `tab += player`.name don't affect my `var tab = "";`

```
tab = "";
for (var id in response.items) {
        clash({request: {proxy: process.env.PROXIMO_URL}}).playerByTag(response.items[id].tag).then(player => {
        tab += player.name;
    })
}

console.log(tab);
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of aynchronous execution. Try to log `tab` right after you add the player name to it, and see the difference.

Comment: `console.log()` prints `tab` way before the function executes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`playerByTag` is running asynchronously, so you can't get the responses synchronously as you're doing now. If you're OK waiting in serial, just put it inside an async function and use `await`:

```
(async () => {
  let tab = "";
  for (let item of response.items) {
    const player = await clash({request: {proxy: process.env.PROXIMO_URL}})
      .playerByTag(item.tag);
    tab += player.name;
  }
  console.log(tab);
})();
```

If you want to run the requests in parallel, you'll have to use Promise.all.